# How do I auto enable modules within an install profile

Tags: distributions

I have created an sample installation profile (based on one that I grabbed from the Acqua Drupal install profiles. Thus far I understand the basic architecture. I add dependancies, but I cant figure out how to enable the modules. For instance, I want to require views, views_ui, and features, and I want those modules to be automatically enabled when I install the profile. I'm assuming I add code somewhere in my .install file within the profile. Can someone give me an example of how I would require and enable views for instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add them as `dependencies` in the .info file. To take a segment from standard.info:

```
dependencies[] = block
dependencies[] = color
dependencies[] = comment
dependencies[] = contextual
dependencies[] = dashboard
```

To add a little reference from [How to Write a Drupal 7 Installation Profile](http://drupal.org/node/1022020):

> The contents of the profilename.info file are as follows:
>
> - The name, description, and core assignments are all required.
> - **The dependencies list includes all modules that will be enabled when this profile is installed (the ones above are the defaults from the Standard install profile).**
> - You can optionally include other declarations that can also appear in module .info files.

(Emphasis mine).

So enabling views would just be:

```
dependencies[] = views
```

And if you want the UI:

```
dependencies[] = views_ui
```

Comment: I added both views and views_ui in that fashion, however, when I install the new profile, the modules are disabled by default, perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: Might be a daft question but is the views module available during the install? And where's it located?

Comment: @Clives answer is correct. If you have added the modules as dependencies, they _will_ be enabled, and if they are not present, the install will fail and abort. To test that your doing the right thing, add a bogus dep, `dependencies[] = BLARGH!`. If that doesn't cause the install to fail and complain about missing module `BLARGH!`, you're editing the wrong file.

Comment: Sorry, I spoke to soon, it did indeed work, I forgot to mention I was using Aegir, I forgot to re-verify the Platform after I changed the install profile, thanks for help